# delete row permanently from database with delete button(laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, delete-row

i want to delete row permanently from database via delete button.

this is my button code in a form that sends id to destroy function.

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/newsmaster/'.$value->id, 'class' => 'form-horizontal create_form', 'files' => true)) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    <button type="submit" class="btn red">Delete</button>
</form>
```

this is my destroy function:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $feed= Feed::find($id);
        $feed->delete();
        Session::flash('message', 'News Deleted Successfully.');
        $redirect = 'admin/newsmaster';
        return Redirect::to($redirect);
    }
```

this is my Feed model:

```
protected $table = 'feed_news';
use SoftDeletes;
protected $softDelete = true;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

my problem is when i click on delete option my row in database doesn't get deleted, instead it updates the deleted_at column.

Comment: Because you are using `SoftDeletes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To permanently remove a soft deleted model from the database, use the [`forceDelete`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_forceDelete) method:

```
$feed= Feed::find($id);
$feed->forceDelete();
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#deleting-models)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Eloquent's [Soft Delete Trait](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting). Therefore, you specified in your `FeedModel` to soft delete the records. By removing its from the model, Eloquent will permanently delete the specific row.

`FeedModel`

```
protected $table = 'feed_news';

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```